# How do I paint() a JFrame in another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, event-dispatch-thread

I am trying to make a JFrame's `paint()` method start a thread and then use `Graphics` to render shapes from that thread (In a separate file). When I try doing this, nothing renders.

```java
//JFrame
public class Window extends JFrame {

    public Window() {

        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.setSize(1280, 720);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        new ThreadForRendering(g).start();
    }
```

```java
// Thread I'm trying to run
public class ThreadForRendering extends Thread {

    private final Graphics g;

    public ThreadForRendering(Graphics g) {
        this.g = g;
    }

    public void run() {
        this.g.setColor(Color.RED);
        this.g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    }
}
```

I have tried adding `super.paintComponent(g);` to the paint method, and also calling `repaint()` on the window after the thread is started, but the window remains blank.

Comment: You _must_ run graphics operations on the event thread; you _may not_ create your own "thread for rendering".

Answer (score 0):

`paint` is called as a response to a needed repainting on the GUI thread, and should happen fast. Breaking out of this scheme can only lead to problems, a black screen the least of worries.

`@Override public void paintComponent` should be your painting implementation.
It should be fast.

If you have complex and slow things to draw, you can fill a `BufferedImage` that you then can draw in the `paintComponnent`.

```
private AtomicReference<BufferImage> imgRef = new AtomicReference<>();

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    BufferedImage img = img.get();
    if (img != null) {
        g2.draw img ...
    }
}
```

In a thread:

```
BufferedImage constructedImg = new ...
Graphics g = constructedImg.createGraphics();
try {
    g.fillRect ...
} finally {
    g.dispose();
}
imgRef.set(constructedImg);
```

In general painting is done intelligently: a JPanel is normally *double buffered*, painting is done in a buffer that then overwrites the actually shown buffer. So in most cases one does not need to resolve to another thread.